# htaccess RewriteCond OR flag not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website and I am trying to filter out certain useragents based on parts of their string names

I'm using this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %[HTTP_USER_AGENT] .*useragent3.* [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %[HTTP_USER_AGENT] .*useragent2.* [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %[HTTP_USER_AGENT] .*useragent1.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Doing so, I get a 500 error and I've noticed that if I remove the **OR** flag I get rid of the 500 error and the website shows up but it does not filter the useragents. This is normal behavior since the **OR** flag adds the OR statement to my RewriteCond query as the default would be **AND** and would require that the useragent name to match all of those strings.

The question remains, why I get a 500 error when using OR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the whitespace in your flags

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %[HTTP_USER_AGENT] .*useragent3.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %[HTTP_USER_AGENT] .*useragent2.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %[HTTP_USER_AGENT] .*useragent1.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Should work

Comment: This goes to the "How to lose 1 hour because of a whitespace" series. Thanks!

Comment: Add another hour for spotting that I should be using {} instead of [] .. doh